# "Жизнь и деяния которых увековечивают легенды и предания" - понятно ли, кто на ком стоял?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Выглядит всё это как синопсис к киносценарию, понимаю. А если
>   представлять себе весь объём информации, то больше похоже на
>   телеграмму. И, наверное, скучновато такое читать, однако без этого
>   краткого ознакомления с главными действующими лицами, **жизнь и деяния
>   которых увековечивают легенды и предания, и главное – отражают фрески
>   монастырей, *те, кому обязаны своим устроением сами обители* – никак
>   невозможно**.

Пожалуйста, в выделенном фрагменте помогите со знаками. По мере возможности - со смыслами.

Comment: "**Те, кому** обязаны" - на **кого** это ссылка? В именительном падеже здесь никого не найти. Невозможно отличить и увековечиваемых от увековечивающих - кто кого (что)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В качестве варианта:

Выглядит всё это как синопсис **киносценария,** понимаю. А если представлять себе весь объём информации, то больше похоже на телеграмму. И наверное, скучновато такое читать, однако без этого краткого ознакомления с главными действующими лицами, жизнь и деяния которых увековечивают легенды и предания **– и главное,  отражают фрески монастырей, обязанных им своим устроением,** – никак невозможно.

Comment: И всё равно нипонил... ***без этого краткого ознакомления <...> никак невозможно*** - если так со смыслами, то не так со знаками.

Comment: А если запятую добавить?

Comment: Ну нарисуй что-нито внутри ответа!

Comment: Да я смысла заданного текста не понимаю. Мне кажется. что речь идет о следующем. Есть главные действующие лица, их жизнь и деяния увековечивают легенды и предания.  Также их жизнь и деяния отражают фрески монастырей, что особенно важно. Причем эти монастыри обязаны своим устроением этим действующим лицам. Если это верно, то в своем варианте текста я это пытаюсь выразить, но по заданному тексту этого не прочитаешь. Или я смысл неправильно понимаю, но тогда в чем он?

Comment: Вот! И пусть наш автор смотрит на свою мысль нашими глазами. Пока молчит. А я все вопросы (большинство без ответов) вместе с правленым текстом вчера отправила. Опять Рим обезынтернетел...

Comment: Да, и я еще добавлю  по исходному тексту. Вот Alex_ander задает вопрос о падеже местоимения "те". Мне тоже кажется, что там должен быть не И.п., а вроде бы Т.п. (лицами - теми). Я пробовала оставить такую структуру, но у меня не получился текст, который можно было бы без труда понять.

Comment: А, вот такая работа. Я ея люблю. Сведу тебя с автором, если ты готова подождать, пока автор разбогатеет... Читала: чтобы делать деньги на книгах, нужно выпускать по читабельной штучке в двумесячье.

Comment: Конечно, я желаю автору скорее разбогатеть. Да вот работа у вас очень ответственная, я только в помощники гожусь.

Comment: Напиши мне о себе linaglat@mail.ru

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, может быть. Я подумаю.

Answer (score 2):

Фраза помпезна и неуклюжа. Одного читателя она огорошит, другого может и отпугнуть.

Предлагаю несколько сжатый и более понятный вариант:

"... однако невозможно двигаться дальше без этого краткого ознакомления с главными действующими лицами -- теми, кому обязаны своим устроением сами обители, и чьи деяния увековечены в легендах и преданиях, и чьи лики мы увидим на фресках этих монастырей".

Comment: А меня отпугивают уныло-однородные линейные фразы, состоящие из   соподчиненных придаточных и одинаковых союзных слов.  Простота далеко не всегда признак совершенства. Конечно, текст должен легко читаться и пониматься без труда, но при этом он должен быть написан художником. Построить художественное пространство не каждому дано,  как и почувствовать его тоже дано не каждому.  И в живописи, и в словесности для этого есть свои приемы. Поэтому при редактировании допускается чуть-чуть подправить  текст, а не перекрашивать его по своему усмотрению.

Comment: @Sharon   Я согласен. Но в данном случае исходный вариант до такой степени неудобоварим, что почти любое изменение (особенно сокращение) пойдёт ему только на пользу.

Comment: Да не любое, в том-то вся трудность. Нужно как бы представить себя на месте писателя, почувствовать его стиль.

Comment: @Sharon  В данном случае этого делать не надо. Не надо отождествляться мыслью с горе-писателем, неспособным выстроить логически завершённую фразу и путающимся в хитросплетениях собственной речи.

Comment: Если следовать Вашей методике оценки художественной литературы, то половину русских писателей-классиков можно назвать горе-писателями. Что за народ! Путаются в собственной речи, логически завершить фразу не могут.

Comment: Меня лично больше пугает другой вариант, когда пишут книги люди с примитивными эмоциями, этакие люди-роботы с пустой душой. Им рассказать миру не о чем, они могут на время занять ваше внимание  интригующим сюжетом и легко читаемые фразы строить умеют.  Но  это всё,  в конце книги вы чувствуете себя обманутым: ни новых мыслей, ни новых чувств, да и сюжет оказался совершенно бессмысленным. В общем, прочитать и забыть Или лучше выбросить.

Comment: Писатели и художники, как я думаю, люди одной профессии. Поэтому хочется здесь вспомнить Б. Окуджаву: "Вы, как СУДЬИ, НАРИСУЙТЕ наши судьбы, Наше лето, нашу зиму и весну… Ничего, что мы ЧУЖИЕ, вы РИСУЙТЕ! Я потом, что непонятно, объясню.